# Creating an array with x elements

Tags: python

I wanna create an array with x elements (defined by the user). Is that possible to do?
Till now I've always done it like this :

```
array = []

l = int(input("Syze: "))

i = 0
while i<l:
    elem = input("Element : ")
    array = array + [elem]
    i = i + 1
```

Is it even possible ?

Comment: you want `array.append(elem)`

Comment: Your code works fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
names = raw_input("Enter the names of your friends separated by spaces: ")
array = names.split()
print(len(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to create the array X with the initial fixed size Y, then you need to create the array after having the input of the user telling the size.
Small example:

```
Size = int(raw_input("Enter the size of the array: "))
MyArray = [None] * Size
idx = 0
while idx < Size:
    MyArray[idx] = raw_input("Content: ")
    idx += 1
```

If the Array X needs to be dynamic, then you should use append
Small example:

```
MyArray = []
while 1:
    UsrInput = raw_input("Content: ")
    if(UsrInput == "EXIT"):
        break
    MyArray.append(UsrInput)
print "MyArray array length: ", len(MyArray)
```